# How to compute $\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos(\pi/x)}{x - \frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos(\pi/x)}{x - \frac{2}{3}}$? I'm stuck in this question. Is there a way not using the l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: The shortest way is to use the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \cos (\dfrac{\pi}{x})$ at $x = \dfrac{2}{3}$ up to second term and you should be done.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ \lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos( \frac{\pi}{x})}{x - \frac{2}{3}} = \lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^2 \cos \left( \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)}{x - \frac{2}{3}} = \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}x^2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{x} \right) \right|_{x=\frac{2}{3}} = -\pi.$$

Answer (score 2):

From $\cos\alpha=-\sin(\dfrac{3\pi}{2}-\alpha)$ write
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{x})}{x - \dfrac{2}{3}}
&=&
\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{x^2 \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{x})}{x - \dfrac{2}{3}}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{-x\sin(\dfrac{3\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{x})}{1-\dfrac{2}{3x}}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{-x\sin(\pi(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{x}))}{\dfrac{2}{3}(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{x})}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\frac{2}{3}}\frac{-x\pi(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{x})}{\dfrac{2}{3}(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{x})}\\
&=&
\color{blue}{-\pi}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Set $x-2/3=y$

$\cos \pi/x=\cos 3\pi/(3y+2)=-\sin(3\pi/2- 3\pi/(3y+2))$